# LinqToExcel to load Dictionary

Tags: c#, performance, linq, dictionary, linq-to-excel

[image]

I have the following worked out but quite less than elegant. I'd like to work this out with ToDictionary if possible. Thank you for any help as I'm pretty new.

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"E:\MAHipotCepaStationProgram.xlsx");
    
//get list of program names
List<string> testNames = new List<string>();
testNames.AddRange(excel.Worksheet().ToList()
            .Where(s => s["Program #"].Value.ToString() == "Program Title")
            .Select(s => s[1].Value.ToString()));

// get list of program numbers
List<int> testNumbers = new List<int>();

testNumbers.AddRange(excel.Worksheet().ToList()
            .Where(s => s["Program #"].Value.ToString() == "Program #")
            .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s[1].Value)));

// combine them
Dictionary<int, string> programs = new Dictionary<int, string>();

for (int x = 0; x < testNames.Count-1; x++)
{
    if (!programs.ContainsKey(Convert.ToInt32(testNumbers[x])))
    {
        programs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(testNumbers[x]), testNames[x]);
    }
    else
    {
        testNumbers[x].Dump("Duplicate Found");
    }
}

programs.Dump("Dict");
```

This is as close as I've gotten, but not right. Error:

> Requires a receiver of type IEnumerable string

which isn't computing with me:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"E:\MAHipotCepaStationProgram.xlsx");
    
Dictionary<string, string> programsDict = excel.Worksheet().ToDictionary<string, string>(
                                        e => e["Program #"].Value.ToString() == "Program Title")
                                            .Select(s => s[1].Value.ToString()),
                                        f => f.Where(d => d.Value.ToString() == "Program #").ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the values using a sigle LINQ query.This will return the name and number columns in the excel:

```
    var sampleExcel = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"I:\Book1.xlsx");
    var sampleWorksheet = from workSheet in sampleExcel.Worksheet("Sheet1") select workSheet;
    var selectedValues = from excelRow in sampleExcel.Worksheet()
       select new { name = excelRow[0], number =Convert.ToInt32(excelRow[1]) };
        foreach (var item in selectedValues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name is {0} ,number is {1}",item.name,item.number));
        }


        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (var item in selectedValues)
        {
            dict.Add(item.number, item.name);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name is {0} ,number is {1}", item.name, item.number));
        }
```

Equivalent lambda expression for the above LINQ query:

```
var selectedValues1 = sampleExcel.Worksheet().Select(x => new { name = x[0], number = x[1] });
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort.  Any way we can do it with ToDictionary though?

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> programsDict =
    excel
        .Worksheet()
        .Select(x => new { A = x[0].ToString(), B = x[1].ToString() })
        .ToArray()
        .Where(x => new [] { "Program #", "Program Title" }.Contains(x.A))
        .Buffer(2)
        .Select(x => new { title = x[0].B, number = int.Parse(x[1].B) })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.number, x => x.title);
```

You just need to NuGet "System.Interactive" to get the `.Buffer(int)` operator.

Or use this implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Buffer<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    =>
        source
            .Select((t, i) => new { t, i })
            .GroupBy(x => x.i / count)
            .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.t).ToArray());
```