# Linq Zip trouble

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
var zip = testNames.Zip(testNumbers, (code, state) => code + ": " + state);
```

returns an `IEnumerable` of strings, how would I get `IEnumerable` string string?

Comment: Use backticks to format code.  What type do you want?

Comment: Make testNames a List() object.  Sometimes testNames.AsEnumerable().Zip will work.  Sometimes using testNames.Cast<add type here>().Zip will solve issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `IEnumberable string string`? That's not a valid type. Do you mean `IEnumerable<<anonyomous type: string, string>>` or `IEnumerable<(string, string)>`?

Answer (score 2):

Here are you two choices, based on what you've given us in your question:

```
var testNames = new [] { "A", "B" };
var testNumbers = new [] { 1, 2 };

var zip1 = testNames.Zip(testNumbers, (code, state) => new { code, state });

var zip2 = testNames.Zip(testNumbers, (code, state) => (code, state));
```

Both are valid C#.

Based on reading your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885021/linqtoexcel-to-load-dictionary) you should need to get in to this `.Zip` scenario. You should be able to read your original data in a single query. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50893205/259769) shows you how.